# Application Insights causing unnecessary GC in Win2D game

Tags: memory-leaks, azure-application-insights, win2d

So I was working on a Win2D game and noticed that once in a while some frames were being skipped. I assumed it was the GC, so I took a couple of memory snapshots to see what's going on. After taking care of my part of the problem and allocating all my memory at the start of the game, I noticed that a lot of **Task< IReadOnlyList< Windows.Storage.StorageFile>>** objects were still being created during gameplay. This was also happening in an empty universal app project and after looking around I figured out that Application Insights was enabled by default and was causing all this.

I don't know much about Application Insights but it seems like something nice to have.
So my question is: Can I still use Application Insights but prevent it from creating all those task objects and accessing the file system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ApplicationInsights uses [PersistenceChannel](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/v1.2.3/src/TelemetryChannels/PersistenceChannel/Shared/PersistenceChannel.cs) that whenever telemetry item is generated stores it on disk and than reads it back and sends (and in case of no internet connection, stores it back and tries later). You can replace in with [InMemoryChannel](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/blob/v1.2.3/src/Core/Managed/Shared/Channel/InMemoryChannel.cs) that would only send telemetry out (but in case of failure telemetry item would be lost). This implementation should be more lightweight since it does not need Storage access, but note that it also does not have retry policy.
So on start you would do smth like this:

`TelemetryConfiguration.Active.Channel.Dispose(); // you may need to cast it here to persistence channel
TelemetryConfiguration.Active.Channel = new InMemoryChannel();`